# sql query does not return the first row

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever i use: `while($x = mysqli_fetch_array($y))` and then `echo $x`, it returns all except the first row. 
The tables:

**forum.users**

- users.user_id

  users.username

  users.password

  users.image

**forum.forums**

- forums.forum_id

  forums.user_id

  forums.name

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "forum");
if(!isset($_SESSION["online"])==1)  {
    $_SESSION["offline"] = "true";
}
$username = $_SESSION["online"];
$u_query = "SELECT * FROM forum.users WHERE users.username = '".$username."'";
$u_result = $con -> query($u_query);
$u_row = mysqli_fetch_array($u_result);
if(isset($_POST["logout"])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
}   
$f_search = "SELECT * FROM forum.forums WHERE user_id = '".$u_row['user_id']."'";
$f_result = $con -> query($f_search);
$f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<charset = "UTF-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head> 
<body>

<div id="header">
    <div id="user">
        <img src="<?php echo $u_row['image']; ?>" id="user-image">
        <?php echo $u_row["username"]; ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="logout" value="sign out">
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>

<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($f_result)>= 0) { ?>
<div>
    <div>Your forums:</div><table><tr>
    <?php while($f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result)) { ?>
    <td><a href="forum.php?forumid=<?php echo $f_row['forum_id']; ?>"><?php echo $f_row["name"]; ?></a></td>
    <td></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr></table>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does it not return the first row?

Comment: Sidenote: `$_SESSION["offline"] = "true"` that might fail you if you're looking to check as boolean later on.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches the row and advances the cursor. So your first

```
$f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result);
```

has the first row. Then

```
while($f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result)) {
```

advances to the second row, and loops through all the other results.

So either get rid of `$f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result);` outside of the `while` or output the contents before the `while`. It doesn't look like you are using that array so I'd just remove it.

Additionally this:

```
$username = $_SESSION["online"];
$u_query = "SELECT * FROM forum.users WHERE users.username = '".$username."'";
```

is open to SQL injections. You should use prepared statements and parameterize the query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also for the note at the end. Don't think i'll need to do it for this asignment, since it's only for high school and my teacher did not understand why i got the first error either. If I have time i migth add it in, or else just keep it in mind next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result);`

By calling that on its own, early in the script, you're advancing the pointer +1. Then in your `while($f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result))` you're actually starting at the second row.

```
$f_search = "SELECT * FROM forum.forums WHERE user_id = '".$u_row['user_id']."'";
$f_result = $con -> query($f_search);
$f_row = mysqli_fetch_array($f_result); // <---- remove this line
```